# Production environment is not working in Symfony2 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I configured sample Symfony2 project using composer.

While running my sample application It is working fine for "dev" environment (i.e, It is working fine for http://test.local/app_dev.php/ url).

But It is not working in "prod" environment (i.e, While hitting http://test.local/).

I am getting 404 page not found error.

Comment: did you probably add your routes only to `app/config/routing_dev.yml` instead of `app/config/routing.yml` ? btw. you can test if symfony has routes for the production environment with `app/console router:debug --env=prod`.

Comment: I did this one. Just now I installed this project. I didn't do any changes. I am working with symfony2 basic setup given by symfony.

Comment: @Gara if you cleared the cache without any issue; I think the URL for prod should be *http://test.local/app.php/* not *http://test.local/* right?

Comment: @Javad: Ya! This is right. I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your setup if you're using the plain `symfony-standard` edition.

`symfony-standard`'s production environment has **no** routes configured by default.

So there is no `/` route and therefore you get a 404 not found error.

Have a look at the default **[`routing.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/routing.yml)** - it's empty.

The *Hello World* example-routes from AcmeDemoBundle are only found in [`routing_dev.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/app/config/routing_dev.yml#L16) (which is loaded only in the dev environment) and will be removed in version 2.5.